# Localization using react typescript

Tags: javascript, .net, json, reactjs, typescript-typings

I am new to React, and I want to localize every component in my project, the component extension is `tsx`.

I want the text to change from English to French.

I have tried using `react-intl` and `react-i18n`.  My problem is that to install these libraries they find on `@types` but my project use `typings`.

Can someone show how to do it manually?  Such as a drop down which shows you languages and when selecting the language the text changes?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just copy the `*.d.ts` files from whatever project has them and use those directly. You can also make a pull request directly if typings are missing for a project that you need them for.

Comment: Hi keith's, 
Do have some examples for like a drop drop list and when you choose the language the whole text change

And for answering my question quickly thanks a lot

Comment: @user8382580 I'm afraid I've not used `react-intl` and `react-i18n` directly to give you an example with them - I added a [reactjs] tag to your question to hopefully get a response from someone that does. I _have_ had to deal with typing issues in TypeScript quite a lot though - I find I nearly always end up with either a couple of `.d.ts` defs locally or having a couple of explicit `any` types about.

Comment: 's thanks a lot
Waiting for others to answer my question

Comment: Is it possible to read a resources file in react Typescript? 
If it is possible please provide me an example 

Thanks

Comment: @user8382580 yes, but we'd need a lot more information to go on - are you localising on the client or server? Assuming the former then you'll need to `fetch` (or whatever AJAX/HTTP method you want) down the resource data and add some caching. `react-intl` [does all of this](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#addlocaledata) but that's probably several Q&As to cover.

Comment: my solution contains 2 asp.net webapi's. The first one use mvc concept and the other use as font end where on this and runnig react typescript and in this project i want to localize the components (.tsx). 

I want to know how to create a resources file and how to call it on a component/s.

This is a Home.tsx file

import * from React from "react";
export class Home extends React.Component<{}{}>
{
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               
                <h2>Welcome everyone!!</h2>
               
            </div>);
    }
}